# ViewPager getItemPosition() never called. Who should call it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a bit puzzled about the `Fragment[State]PagerAdapter`. Basically my issue is that I need to change the content (Fragments) of a `ViewPager` depending on screen orientation. I read a number of posts on this and some say I should override `getItemPosition(Object)` from `PagerAdapter`. I have done this but the method is never called, and I can't find any call to it in `PagerAdapter`, `FragmentPagerAdapter` nor `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Anyone out there know how this works and mind explaining?

Currently I made an ugly hack in my `instantiateItem()` to test a theory of mine, but this is nothing I really want to use. As you can see I remove the fragment if `getItemPosition()` return `POSITION_NONE`. In `getItemPosition()` I have some logic to determind if a fragment should still be in the pager or not.

```
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            // Hack since getItemPosition is never called.
            final long itemId = getItemId(position);
            String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
            Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
            if(fragment != null && getItemPosition(fragment) == POSITION_NONE) {
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
                mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
            }

            fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }
```

JavaDoc says:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object)

Called when the host view is attempting to determine if an item's position
has changed. Returns POSITION_UNCHANGED if the position of the given
item has not changed or POSITION_NONE if the item is no longer present
in the adapter.

The default implementation assumes that items will never
change position and always returns POSITION_UNCHANGED.

@param object Object representing an item, previously returned by a call to
            instantiateItem(View, int).
@return object's new position index from [0, getCount()),
        POSITION_UNCHANGED if the object's position has not changed,
        POSITION_NONE if the item is no longer present.
```

I have tested my code on API level 19 and 22 and the issue is the same.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`. If I extend `PagerAdapter` and wrote me own instantiate and destroy methods I might be able to workaround this. Was hoping I would not have too though. Plus it's annoying to not understand it. ;)

Comment: I don't think you have to do anything like that.  The PagerAdapter would normally be recreated when the Activity is recreated on screen orientation.  You would, instead, just change which fragments get instantiated by the Adapter.

Comment: (Updated) I think the `FragmentManager` recreate the fragments on rotate, and the Adapter does not recreate them again. At least they are not recreated on rotate when I trace the code. I do extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` and not `PagerAdapter`, might be that the latter prevent automatic recreation of fragments.

Answer (score 2):

`getItemPosition()` is only called after a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call.

So first, modify your data set and then make a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call.
You will also have to override `getItemId()` to return a static identifier. By default it returns the position given.

Comment: After calling **notifyDataSetChange** , it re-instantiate other views, which i don't want. What i suppose to do after deleting a view, so that other view stays as it is ?\

Answer (score 0):

`getItemPosition()` is called after `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called on the adapter.  That's like saying you want to change which fragments are in the `ViewPager`.

For your case, if you're making changes on screen orientation, the entire activity is probably being taken down and rebuilt, so it's just a matter of having the adapter do the right thing. In very simplistic terms:

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        if (orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // ... set up the views for portrait
        } else {
            // ... set up the views for landscape
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the `notifyDataSetChanged()` some time ago and it's not working as expected. I guess if I only extended `PagerAdapter` and not `Fragment(State)PagerAdapter` your solution might work. The latter will however "remember" the fragments on rotate and never recreate them (Maybe it's the `FragmentManager` that recreate them). I was under the impression `getItemPosition()` would say if it had to be recreated or not. I was hoping I would not have to write my own instantiate and destroy code.  :)